# Can't query with condition on relation nestjs/mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

I have an ***Item*** model, and a ***Category*** Model.  
The ***item*** model has a *reference* (ObjectId) to the ***Category*** model.
I am writing code to **get the items in a specific category**. 
So i get the id of the category as a paremeter(of type string) to the service,
then write "return this.ItemModel.find({category: id}).exec();".
where 'category' is the reference to the Category model, 
and 'id' is the id passed to the API call.
I get the error "No Overload Matches This Call".

How can i solve this?

**Item Schema**

```
export type ItemDocument = Item & Document;
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Item {
  @Prop()
  name_en: string;
  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' })
  category: Category;
}
export const ItemSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Item);
```

**Category Schema**

```
export type CategoryDocument = Category & mongoose.Document;
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Category {
  @Prop()
  name_en: string;
}
export const CategorySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Category);
```

**category.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Category.name)
    private categoryModel: mongoose.Model<CategoryDocument>,
    @InjectModel(Item.name)
    private readonly ItemModel: mongoose.Model<ItemDocument>,
  ) {}
  findOneCatItems(id: string) {
    return this.ItemModel.find({category: id}).exec(); --> Error Line
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full error you're getting? [Mongoose supports passing filter objects](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned here

> The item model has a reference (ObjectId) to the Category model.

but the `category` property of the `Item` model is typed as a `Category`.

When you do this:
`this.ItemModel.find({category: id}).exec();`

You are providing a type of `ObjectId` where a type of `Category` is expected.

Since you are not saving the entire category object on an item, change the definition in your Item class to:

```
@Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' })
  category: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
```

**Note**: if you are passing `id` as a string here `this.ItemModel.find({category: id}).exec();`, Then typing category as a string instead of ObjectId will work

Comment: thanks alot!
this seems to work!
but on the documentation, the example uses the class(in the example, it is Owner), instead of mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId.
What is the difference between these two?